# Spacy returns empty results

Tags: python, python-2.7, spacy

I've installed spacy following the instructions on the website for python 2.7 using pip and downloaded the English models, also using pip, however when I run a simple test code it returns a empty set as a result, when the example online indicates it should identify the subject.  I think that spacy is not connecting to the models, and therefore not returning any results, but it gives me no errors and indicates that it has connected properly.

```
from spacy.en import English

nlp = English()
sent = "I shot an elephant"
doc = nlp(sent)

sub_toks = [tok for tok in doc if (tok.dep_ == "nsubj")]

print sub_toks
```

This returns `[]`, no errors or any other issues.  How do I get it to actually return a result?

Comment: This returns `[I]` for me.  Make sure your input is unicode and not a string, i.e. `sent = u"I shot an elephant"`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the English models didn't load correctly.  When I reinstalled I saw that despite the fact that command prompt said 'Linked successfully' the line above it was 'you do not have sufficient rights to perform this operation', I ran it as an administrator and it worked

Answer (score 0):

@Neil Carey,

Try to install Spacy 1.9, its the stable version I am facing same problem I install Spacy 1.9 and its work form me OR Try to Run this Command in shell

```
pip install -U spacy

python -m spacy download en

OR you can link your package to spacy like This

python -m spacy link [package name or path] [shortcut] [--force]
```